# identifying a strict partial order by its set of incomparable pairs

Tags: order-theory

Given a strict partial order $>$ over a set $A$. Any two elements of $A$ can be comparable or incomparable. The information I have about $>$ is of the following form :

$(a,b)$ are comparable or $(a,b)$ are incomparable. For every pair of elements $a,b\in A$.

Can we define $>$ by having access to this type of information? If not, are there certain subclass of strict partial orders that can be identified by this type of information?

Comment: Suppose $A$ has $n$ elements and there are **no** incomparable pairs. Then all we know about $\lt$ is that it's one of the $n!$ total orders on $A.$ Do you want to reconstruct the actual partial order, or just "up to isomorphism"?

Comment: If you reverse the order (replace $\lt$ with $\gt$) you get exactly the same incomparable pairs. So the only time you can reconstruct the partial order is when **all** pairs are incomparable.